# aptana crashes on svn update

Tags: crash, aptana

Running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.2.201208201020 on windows.

When I try to team/update to HEAD/ it crashes and close. When I come back to svn, it is locked, and  I need to clean/refresh, but it will crash again.

here is the paste of the hs_err_pid.*_*_.log file: http://pastebin.com/aiuN6DMU

thank you